# angularjs add new model property for view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new at angularjs and getting data from api like this:

```
 function response(data){
    $scope.data = data
 }

  <<<< data format is ilke this >>>>>
  [
    {"id":"1", "name":"item1"}, 
    {"id":"2", "name":"item2"},
    {"id":"3", "name":"item3"}
  ];
  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>
```

Using this in view page with ng-repeat:

```
<button ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.name}}</button>
```

I will change selected item button color. But I need **selected** property on items. But it does not comes from database.

How can I add  property named **selected** to items? in view or in controller?

Comment: `$scope.data[0].selected = true;` inside your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `ng-init` in repeat as,

```
<button ng-repeat="item in data" ng-init="item.selected = false">{{item.name}}</button>
```

this will add a `selected` property for each and every repeating object with the value of `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a simple loop ?

```
$.each($scope.data, function( index, item ) {
  item.selected = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the selected attribute for all data items:

```
for (var i in data){
   data[i].selected = false;
}
```

and then change it on click:

```
<button ng-repeat="item in data" ng-click="item.selected=true">{{item.name}}</button>
```